# Javascript - Detecting Opinionated Text

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, google-chrome-extension, command-line

I'm trying write a script that detects, and highlights, opinionated strings in web pages. I can highlight the text just fine, but I'm having trouble detecting the opinionated text. As an alpha version, maybe simply putting in a list of strings (ei: I think, This is, etc) and if it detects those strings, highlighting the entire sentence they're in. I'm not sure how complicated the code will have to be to make this, but currently I'm not sure how to even test this current function because I don't know how to execute it, to make it running every time you open a new web page. Would I put it in background.js? This code is currently in a file named algorithm.js. Thanks!

```
 var result;
 var scanned;
 function opinion(); {
     if (
  (
    document.documentElement.textContent || document.documentElement.innerText
  ).indexOf('I think', 'This is', 'He is', 'She is') > -1
) {
  var result = 1;
  console.log('Detected Opinion');
  return;
}
```

Comment: What issues are you experiencing with your current approach?

Comment: Remove the `;` after the function name.

Comment: This is going to be quite hard to do well. (Oh, look at that!. It would have correctly flagged that last statement as opinion)

Comment: We're not going to design your algorithm for you. Design your algorithm, try to implement it, and come back if you run into specific problems with it.

Comment: The main problem is that I need to figure out how and where to call this function, and I haven't been able to test out the function because it won't get called for some odd reason. Where would I call it? (Sorry if this is a basic question and excuse me for being dumb). In the backgrounds.js file? This code itself is in a file called algorithm.js

Comment: So please review and edit your question accordingly. The question currently asks another thing then you describe in your comment ("but if anyone could give it a try").

Comment: Start by going here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview to learn where the code should go (almost certainly it will be a content script) and look at the samples page - there is a sample for every configuration of extension design and you can use one as a starting point.